# repeating many times after enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i focus on the input field and hit enter, everything is ok, but when i do that again it repeat twice or more, depend how many time i focus

```
  $(document).delegate(".changeValue","focus one",function(){   

        $(this).on("keydown", function (event) {

            $(this).parent().find('.logisticError').remove();

            if(event.keyCode == 13){

                var amountVal = /^\d+(\.)\d{2}$/

                if (!$(this).val().match(amountVal)) {

                    $(this).parent().append("<span class='logisticError'>you have an error</span>");

                } else {

                    field = $(this).data('field');
                    updateOrder(field, $(this).val());
                    $(this).blur();

                }           
            }       
        });
    });
```

Comment: Consider only using `.on()` as it has superseded `.delegate()`

Comment: @technophobia thx, i switch to .on()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are creating an event every time someone is focussing the field `.changeValue`, so the first time you create an event, the second time it will create another event, equal to the first one.

I suggest you to remove the delegate stuff (deprecated btw) and bind directly the field on document ready

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.changeValue').on("keydown", function (event) .....
});
```

so the bind is done jsut one time, not every time the user focus the field

Comment: Thx. I also remove focus (i think that was major problem) and now everyhing working fine.